# MongoDB updating multiple fields using values from same docs fields

Tags: mongodb

For example:

```
$collection
->update(
    array(
        'Counter' => array('$gt' => 10)
    ),
    array(
        '$set' => array(
            'Value' => {'Counter'} * 1.05
        )
    ),
    array('multiple' => true)
);
```

Where **{'Counter'}** - is a counter field value from updated MongoDB document.

Need to update all **Value** = **Counter** * 1.05 where **Counter** > 10.